# How to make the sections get a value of height equal to parts of this image?

Tags: html, image, css

**[JSFiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Pdr/64/)**

How do I make the sections of the `col-right` in the 'WHAT I HAVE' part of the image get the height equal to the part of the image it is opposite to?

[image]

***QUESTION EXPLAINED:***

The image has a height `1610px` (and a width of `700px`), where the pink part is `440px` in height, blue is `380px`, green is `380px`, and yellow is `380px` in height. This is one image, I checked those dimensions in Adobe PS.

Now what I want is that each section/part in the `.col-right` (i.e. the part having an `h3` and `h5` element) should have a `height` same as that of the part of the image to its right, that is the part/section containing the first `h3` and `h5` in `.col-right` should have the same height as that of the pink part of the image.

How can I do that?

***WHAT I TRIED:***

I tried to give each `section` in `col-right` a `height` of `440px`,`380px`,`380px`, and `380px` respectively, but obviously that did not work because the `img` under consideration is getting  the dimension values according to those of the parent element because it has percentage values of `width:50%` and `height:80%`.

Anyways, you can look at the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Pdr/63/).

```css
    @import url(<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,300,600,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>);
    .section-big {
      padding: 100px 0;
    }
    .section-big .container {
      width: 970px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .section-big .col {
      width: 47%;
      display: inline-block
    }
    .section-big .col-left {
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    .section-big .col-right {
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .section-big .col-left img {
      height: 80%;
      width: 50%;
    }
    h3 {
      color: #6c6969;
      transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 40px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    h5 {
      color: #6c6969;
      transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section-big">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-left">
      <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9642/57q0fpdevvo1999zg.jpg?size_id=b" alt="Tun Tun!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-right">
      <section class="section-one">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="section-two">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="section-three">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="section-four">
        <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

---

@gui47 Here!

[image]

Comment: Is it ok to edit the html?

Comment: @sdcr Yes, you can edit the html.

Comment: Is it need to be responsive?

Comment: Yes, I will have to make it responsive eventually, although not dealing with the responsive part right now.

Comment: Take a look of [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nno6wvqr/) I think background image is a better choice than inline for it.

Comment: @sdcr Hey this is really close, the only problem is that why does the image take 100% the `height` and `width` of the its parent i.e. `col-left`?? Likewise for sections in `col-right`. =s

Comment: I set it to table-layout: fixed so that left and right col always equal width, the image is always 100% height and flexible width, so that the right col can responses to it, remember everything is percentage. I also made a inline image [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nek1vgzd/) not sure if you want it.

Comment: @sdcr This looks like what I need. If you can post both of them in an answer, I will mark it as accepted answer. =) Thank you.

Comment: Hi, posted it as an answer, let me know if there is anything else I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are 2 ways of doing it, either way in order to make it to be responsive everything has to be set to percentage height.

See the following demos.

**1.** To use inline image.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/331tcxr7/)**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
.col img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.col h3, .col h5 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.col section:nth-child(1) {
    height: 29%;
}
.col section:nth-child(2) {
    height: 22%;
}
.col section:nth-child(3) {
    height: 23%;
}
.col section:nth-child(4) {
    height: 25%;
}
.col section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: aqua;
}
.col section:nth-child(even) {
    background: lime;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-big">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col col-left">
            <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9642/57q0fpdevvo1999zg.jpg?size_id=b" alt="Tun Tun!" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <section class="section-one">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-two">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-three">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-four">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**2.** To use background image.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpwv7v89/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.section-big { /* change the width/height here */
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
.col-left {
    background: url("http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9642/57q0fpdevvo1999zg.jpg?size_id=b");
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
.col h3, .col h5 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.col section:nth-child(1) {
    height: 30%;
}
.col section:nth-child(2) {
    height: 22%;
}
.col section:nth-child(3) {
    height: 22%;
}
.col section:nth-child(4) {
    height: 26%;
}
.col section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: aqua;
}
.col section:nth-child(even) {
    background: lime;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-big">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col col-left">
            <!-- <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9642/57q0fpdevvo1999zg.jpg?size_id=b" alt="Tun Tun!" /> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col col-right">
            <section class="section-one">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-two">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-three">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
            <section class="section-four">
                <h3>HEADING</h3>
                <h5>Paragraph paragraph</h5>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```